# How to test for undeclared variable in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

```
it("is undefined", function() {
    expect(total).toBe(undefined);
});
```

This spec fails: `ReferenceError: total is not defined`

How to test that a variable has not been declared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The test in jasmine is the same as if you were checking for a normal undefined variable:

```
(typeof total === 'undefined')
```

You can use this with jasmine like:

```
expect(typeof total).toBe('undefined');
```

The [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) returns a string and has the special behavior of not throwing if its operand has not been defined.

Note that jasmine [does have `toBeDefined` matchers](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-Included_Matchers), which are preferred when you can safely access the object (typically if it is a member and you know the parent exists). Depending on how your test is set up, if the variable you are interested in is a member of `this` or `window` or some other scope, you can use those matchers:

```
expect(this.total).toBeDefined();
```

If you can use these, you should.

Comment: OK, that works. Is there any special reason you don't use parentheses with  `typeof``? I thought Javascript requires parens for function calls.

Comment: typeof is not a function. It's an operator. see here for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: `typeof` isn't a function, it's a specialized operator. You don't use parens with `a + b` or `-a`, so `typeof` takes advantage of that syntax.

Comment: Is there any special reason that `that this.total` can use `toBeDefined()` but `total` cannot?

Comment: Because `this.total` returns `undefined` if `this` does not have a property `total`, but `total` will throw if the current scope does not have a variable `total` defined (especially in strict mode).

Comment: Just for clarity: both `typeof myVar` and `typeof(myVar)` are valid syntaxes.